# Joomla .htaccess redirect on multilingual site

Tags: joomla-4.x, redirect

My website has 4 languages (`/en`, `/ka/`, `am/`, `az/`) and we have a situation where we need to replace old menu aliases so that shared links on Facebook still work.

The following battery of redirect rules works most of the time, but not always.

```
RedirectMatch 301 paktmetri(.*) /akhali-ambebi/$1
RedirectMatch 301 faktmetr(.*) /lrahos/$1
RedirectMatch 301 fakt-metr(.*) /yeni-xeberler/$1
RedirectMatch 301 fact-checker(.*) /news/$1
```

When I come from a Facebook url it works, but if I change the language during that visit and then re-visit from Facebook it doesn't because the language is not changed automatically.

Comment: For clarification, are you saying that you want the user's selected language (in their session) to be preserved/respected even if they come from a Facebook link which indicates another language?

Comment: yes, exactly I mean this

Comment: Can you share some examples of the links in Facebook showing what they are and then what you expect them to be resolved to? At the .htaccess level it would have no awareness of the language selected in Joomla therefore you might have to look at using either the core Redirects or a 3rd party extension to handle the redirect once the visitor reaches Joomla.